# Cache lookup failed for function 1 while activating PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm using PostgreSQL 10.5 on a remote server (Debian). I created a database inside then I attempted to enable PostGIS but it wasn't successful.

I had this error : `cache lookup failed for function 1.`

> PostGIS is a spatial extension used in GIS to allow a DataBase
>   Management System manipulate geographical data.

If you have an idea about how to solve this issue, I would be pleased to learn from you.

Comment: How did you install PostgreSQL and postgis?  What command did you execute to get this error? Was it just the CREATE EXTENSION, or something else?

Comment: Yes I did just execute CREATE EXTENSION postgis

Comment: It works for me on a fresh ubuntu 18.04, installing postgis (and postgresql 10, which is a dependency of postgis) using "apt".  I think you may have mixed and matched versions installed.

Comment: It reinstalled postgresql and postgis and it worked fine